# Failed to import numpy python module in PyCharm

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I am learning Python in my free time. I am pretty new. I use PyCharm for IDE.
When I: 
`import numpy as np` 
it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

When I: 
`pip3 install numpy` 
it says: 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.15.4)

When I go to PyCharm - base interpreter is set to: 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/3.7/bin/python3`

The only suspicious thing I find is that Location of environment in PyCharm is set `/Users/XXX/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv`
I read a little bit about environments and it makes logic if I have installed numpy in one env and use another in the IDE, but not sure how to check this.
Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really because of the virtual environment. I installed numpty in the specified in my PyCharm project virtual environment and it worked. I did this by opening PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project Interpreter and I saw that for my project the following virtual env is configured:

[image: Project Interpreter in PyCharm]

I activated it by source `/Users/XXX/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/venv/bin/activate`
and then `pip3 install numpy`

Another option is to change the interpreter to some containing all packages installed.

[image: Change interpreter]